# Nothing appearing on screen, with Matter.js

Tags: javascript, html, matter.js

I was following a tutorial for Matter.js and used it, but nothing appeared on my screen? Can someone help? Also just for conformation, nothing is appearing on the canvas, and the canvas is white to the black background. All the other posts did not help at all :|

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>square.</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.17.1/matter.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts.js"></script>
 <style>
 canvas {
 position: relative;
 width: 500px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: white;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body onload='init()'>
 <div id="areaToRender">
 </div>
 <div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let Engine = Matter.Engine
    Render = Matter.Render
    Runner = Matter.Runner
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies
    Composite = Matter.Composite
    Composties = Matter. Composites
    Constraint = Matter.Constraint
    Mouse = Matter.Mouse 
let MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint
    Events = Matter.Events
let engine;
let render;
let runner;

function init() {
    engine = Engine.create();
}

render = Render.create({
    element: document.getElementById("areaToRender"),
    engine: engine,
    options: {
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        pixelRatio: 1,
        background : '#fafafa',
        wireframes: false
    }
});

Render.run(render);
runner = Runner.create();
Runner.run(runner, engine);

let lastClear = "(not given)"
function clearWorld(exampleName) {
    if (lastClear != exampleName) {
        lastClear = exampleName

        Matter.Composite.clear(engine.world, false)
    }
}

function StartBoxes() {
    clearWorld("Boxes")
    let boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
    let boxB = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80, {
        render: {
            fillStyle: 'red',
            strokeStyle: 'blue',
            lineWidth: 3
        }
    });

let ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true});

Composite.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

Engine.update(engine);

}
```

Even after several tutorials, none worked. P.S using VS Code to edit.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can replace your `init` function with simple assignment to engine variable, because `Render.create` fires earlier, and gets engine value as undefined. And you also forgot to invoke `StartBoxes` function.

```js
// ...
// assign Engine.create() to engine variable, after all previous variable declaraions
engine = Engine.create();

render = Render.create({
  element: document.getElementById("areaToRender"),
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    pixelRatio: 1,
    background: "#fafafa",
    wireframes: false
  }
});

Render.run(render);
runner = Runner.create();
Runner.run(runner, engine);

let lastClear = "(not given)";
function clearWorld(exampleName) {
  if (lastClear !== exampleName) {
    lastClear = exampleName;

    Composite.clear(engine.world, false);
  }
}

function StartBoxes() {
  clearWorld("Boxes");
  let boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
  let boxB = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80, {
    render: {
      fillStyle: "red",
      strokeStyle: "blue",
      lineWidth: 3
    }
  });

  let ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, { isStatic: true });

  Composite.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);

  Engine.update(engine);
}

// invoke StartBoxes function
StartBoxes();
```

Comment: can you post the init change, because i just followed a tutorial, and i don't know much about matter.js. also i'm a loser at js lol

Comment: Just replace the init() function with this line:
engine = Engine.create();
It goes under the multiple variable declarations in beginning of your js snippet

Comment: uh so basically i just take out the function and just leave the engine = Engine.create() function alone

Comment: also do i just delete the init function?, because that line is right below, the same thing

Comment: Yeah, right. You should also invoke StartBoxes function, that line is the last one in my snippet

Comment: still not working, i'll just try ammo.js

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've tried multiple tutorials.

Comment: Doesn't matter anymore, work on codepen but not on vscode. Thanks for you help though.

Comment: I see, I've also tested it on codepen. Must be something wrong with environment then.

Answer (score 0):

When an HTML page loads, it generally loads resources and scripts top to bottom, executing them as it goes.

So the order of your code is currently:

1. Load and execute `scripts.js`, which includes some function definitions like `init`, plus some mainline code that starts Matter.js (`render = Render.create({ ...` etc).
2. Load the DOM, which includes the Matter.js canvas container element `<div id="areaToRender"></div>`.
3. Run `init()` once the DOM load event is fired.

But this is mixed up. The DOM must load before any Matter.js initialization code runs, so that the `document.getElementById("areaToRender")` call will succeed (i.e. not return `null`). Furthermore, `init()` needs to run before the mainline JS code.

There are a few ways to achieve this. One way is to simply make your whole script mainline JS code, without functions, but ensure the script loads after the DOM does.

Another approach is to put all Matter.js initialization code in a callback that runs on the load event. This lets you put the script anywhere.

Here's the second option, which feels a bit closer to what you're going for:

```js
let engine;
let render;
let runner;

function init() {
  engine = Matter.Engine.create();
  render = Matter.Render.create({
    element: document.getElementById("areaToRender"),
    engine: engine,
    options: {
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      pixelRatio: 1,
      background: "#fafafa",
      wireframes: false,
    },
  });
  runner = Matter.Runner.create();
  Matter.Render.run(render);
  Matter.Runner.run(runner, engine);
  startBoxes();
}

let lastClear = "(not given)";
function clearWorld(exampleName) {
  if (lastClear !== exampleName) {
    lastClear = exampleName;
    Matter.Composite.clear(engine.world, false);
  }
}

function startBoxes() {
  clearWorld("Boxes");
  const boxA = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80);
  const boxB = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, 80, 80, {
    render: {
      fillStyle: "red",
      strokeStyle: "blue",
      lineWidth: 3,
    },
  });
  const ground = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(400, 610, 810, 60, {isStatic: true});
  Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, [boxA, boxB, ground]);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>square.</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    <style>
      canvas {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <div id="areaToRender"></div>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that I'm calling `startBoxes()` from `init()` so you can see something on the screen. I've made a few additional cosmetic changes, like using the `Matter.` prefix on all classes (this is a bit more typing, but makes ownership much clearer to distinguish Matter.js library code from your code, or other libraries you may use). I've also used `const` instead of `let`, formatted the code with [Prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/) and removed an unnecessary `Engine.update()` call (the runner will handle this).

By the way, I'm not necessarily endorsing the design here, just getting you up and running.